# In JavaScript do we need to take care of Garbage Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript i use ajax calls to load large data, then bind that to Grid or Dropdown like this

```
$.ajax({  
url: 'some/url',  
    dataType: 'json',  
    method: 'GET',  
    data: {  
        param1: 'param1',  
        param2: 'param2'  
    },  
    success: function(response){  
         var data = response;  
         // bind data to Dropdown or Grid  
         // THEN SHOULD I DO "data = null;"  
    },  
    error: function(response) {  
         console.log(response);  
    }  
});
```

Comment: you don't actually need `data`.

Comment: but somewhere i read that always assign value to local variable and then use that local variable

Comment: In general, no, you do not need to worry about garbage collection

Comment: in this case what you have is an object or array, assigning it to a local variable is just going to store the reference to it in another location. modifying `data` also modifies `response`. there's no real value (or harm, for that matter) in duplicating. but even if you did, and you set `data` to `null`, the data is still stored, and referenced by `response`, until the function completes.

Comment: Note that if you pass the data on to another function that stores a reference to it, it will remain in memory for as long as that other function stores a reference to it.

Comment: O @KevinB now i understand, the webApp was bit slow because i was loading more and more data and adding many references to that data. but you cleared my concepts.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management this will help you

Answer (score 1):

No you don't really need to worry about garbage collection. Once a variable has fallen out of scope the garbage collector will automatically reclaim the memory. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

One thing to bare in mind is that JavaScript is always pass by reference unless it's a [primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). So when you make modifications to your `data` variable, you're pointing to the same memory as response. So technically you have 2 pointers to the same memory.